# Can MongoDB databases be stored in different directories?

Tags: mongodb

I'm having trouble figuring out the answer to this one:

- Am I supposed to run one instance of MongoDB for each directory location?
- Or am I supposed to store all databases in the same location?
- Or Do I run one MongoDB instance and can specify a different location for each database at run time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the --directoryperdb option of mongodb to store each DB in a different physical location.